# Calculate the value of expression.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, inverse-function

If $$ f'(x)>0  \,\forall  x\in \mathbb R^+ \text{ where  }f:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R $$ and
 $$    f(x)+\cfrac{1}{x} = f^{-1}\left(\cfrac{1}{f(x)}\right) $$
Also given that $$ f^{-1}\left(\cfrac{1}{f(x)}\right)>0$$
Then find out the value of $$\cfrac{π}{\sin^{-1}f(2)}$$
I tried some hit and trial to get f(2) but was unable to do so further I tried replacing $$f(x)\to y$$ then further substitutions but keep messing up every time.

Further please suggest better tags if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around for a while, I stumbled upon the trick:

Rewrite the equation as $$f\left(f(x) + \frac 1x\right) = \frac 1{f(x)}$$

First note that $f(x) < 0$ for all $x$:

let $M = f(\infty) := \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, $f(x) < M$ for all $x$. Letting $x \to \infty$ in the formula, $f(M) = \frac 1M$ and letting $x = M$, $f\left(\frac 1M + \frac 1M\right) = M$ which cannot be if $M$ is finite and not $0$. But assuming $M = \infty$ leads to $f(\infty) = 0$ and $M > f(1) > -\infty$, so $M$ can only be $0$.

Now, let $y = f(2)$, then $$f\left(y +\frac 12\right) = f\left(\frac {2y + 1}2\right) = \frac 1y$$
Letting $x = \frac{2y+1}2$,
$$f\left(\frac 1y + \frac 2{2y+1}\right) = f\left(\frac {4y+1}{y(2y+1)}\right) = \frac 1{\frac 1y} = y$$

But $f$ is injective. There can be only one value $x$ with $f(x) = y$. Therefore we must have
$$\frac {4y+1}{y(2y+1)} = 2$$
$y$ will be the negative root.

You can generalize this to find a closed form for $f$.

Comment: Thank You for your efforts.